# Keras model with high accuracy but poor predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, theano

I am trying to train a neural network to make Inverse Kinematics calculations for a robotic arm with predefined segment lengths. I am not including the segment lengths in neural network inputs but rather through the training data. The training data is a pandas dataframe with the spatial mappings of the arm, with labels being the angles of rotation for the three segments of the arm and the features being the solutions of the x and y coordinates of where the endpoint of the last segment would end up in.

I am using Keras with Theano as the Backend.

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(3, input_shape=(2,), activation="relu"),
Dense(3, activation="relu"),
Dense(3)
])

model.summary()

model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(samples, labels, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=1000, epochs=10,shuffle=True, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(samples, labels, batch_size=32, verbose=1)

print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

weights = model.get_weights()
predictions = model.predict(samples, verbose=1)
print predictions
model.save("IK_NN_7-4-3_keras.h5")

OUTPUT===============================================================


Train on 6272736 samples, validate on 1568184 samples
Epoch 1/10
 - 5s - loss: 10198.7558 - acc: 0.9409 - val_loss: 12149.1703 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 2/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.9105 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12117.0527 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 3/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7862 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12113.3804 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 4/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7567 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12050.8211 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 5/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7271 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12036.5538 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 6/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7350 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12103.8665 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 7/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7553 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12175.0442 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 8/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7282 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12161.4815 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 9/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7213 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12101.4021 - val_acc: 0.9858
Epoch 10/10
 - 5s - loss: 4272.7909 - acc: 0.9932 - val_loss: 12152.4966 - val_acc: 0.9858
Test score: 5848.549130022683
Test accuracy: 0.9917127071823204
[[ 59.452095 159.26912  258.94424 ]
 [ 59.382706 159.41936  259.25183 ]
 [ 59.72419  159.69777  259.48584 ]
 ...
 [ 59.58721  159.33467  258.9603  ]
 [ 59.51745  159.69331  259.62595 ]
 [ 59.984367 160.5533   260.7689  ]]
```

Both the test accuracy and validation accuracy are seem good but they don't exactly reflect the reality. The predictions should have looked something like this

```
[[  0   0   0]
[  0   0   1]
[  0   0   2]
...
[358 358 359]
[358 359 359]
[359 359 359]]
```

Since I fed back the same features expecting to get the same labels. Instead I'm getting this numbers for some reason:

```
[[ 59.452095 159.26912  258.94424 ]
 [ 59.382706 159.41936  259.25183 ]
 [ 59.72419  159.69777  259.48584 ]
 ...
 [ 59.58721  159.33467  258.9603  ]
 [ 59.51745  159.69331  259.62595 ]
 [ 59.984367 160.5533   260.7689  ]]
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Lacking your test data to confirm, my intuition is that your model has too few nodes in the interior layer, and maybe needs to be deeper.

Comment: @TomServo "Lacking your test data to confirm" to confirm what? "model has too few nodes in the interior layer, and maybe needs to be deeper" I am not saying this is incorrect but if the answer is that it needs more nodes then why does it give me high accuracy results?

Comment: Accuracy makes no sense in this case, you are doing regression, not classification. Accuracy is a classification metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your metric is accuracy and you are predicting continuous values. You get predictions, but they don´t make any sense. Your problem is a regression and your metric is for classification. You could just use "MSE" "R²" or other regression metrics

```
from keras import metrics
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[metrics.mean_squared_error, metrics.mean_absolute_error])
```

Additionally you should consider increasing the number of neurons and if your input data is really only 2 dimensions, think about some shallow models, not ANNs. (SVM with gauss kernel e.g.)

Comment: Well I'm not using a SVM because I am not classifying anything and I don't think a shallow model will help a lot. I am basically trying to bypass solving the really tedious mathematical model of inverse kinematic arms with more than two segments. I don't know any other ML model that could achieve this. I fixed the metrics and substituted accuracy for mean absolute error since MSE was already being displayed. I also increased the number of nodes to 300/300 and then tried 500/500.

Comment: SVM can also be used for Regression problems, just google for SVR, it has less hyper params, maybe you can achieve a good result.

Comment: Can a SVR model have multiple outputs? I completely understand how to get a single output using multiple inputs with a linear regression model but I'm not sure how a regression model could possibly give me a solution with more than one output dimensions

Comment: Well you could have a model for each output.

Comment: In that case, you are fine with ANNs :)